# Cucumber.js - name of profile in steps definitions

Tags: javascript, cucumber

I would like to find out name of profile used via CLI in step definition. But I can't see any example or doc for this.

cucumber-js -p

I use latest CucumberJS (3.1.0)

thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's best solution but I used Node process.argv.